# After Enabling the namespace class not executed from LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, json, developer, 2gp

I have a LWC that passed the parameter as an Object, which worked fine. However, after enabling the org's namespace, the apex method was not executed with that object parameter and threw an Internal server error. When I modified the object parameter into the JSON.stringify then it executes the apex class.

Below is the code before enabling the namespace:

```
**Apex class code:**
 @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveData(TemplateWrapperTest thetemplateDetails){

}

public class TemplateWrapperTest{
    @AuraEnabled
    public String testStr1 {get;set;}
   @AuraEnabled
    public String testStr2 {get;set;}
}
```

**LWC JS code:**

```
 var dataToSave = {
          testStr1 : this.contactCountryValue,
          testStr2 : this.contactStateValue,
        }
        saveData({ thetemplateDetails: dataToSave })
          .then(result => {
            this.showSpinner = false;
    }
```

Below is the code that works when parameter object changed to JSON:

```
**Apex class code:**
 @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveData(String thetemplateDetails){

}

**LWC JS Code:**
    var dataToSave = {
          testStr1 : this.contactCountryValue,
          testStr2 : this.contactStateValue,
        }
        saveData({ thetemplateDetails: JSON.stringify(dataToSave)})
          .then(result => {
            this.showSpinner = false;
    }
```

Could you guys please help me find out why object passing is not working after enabling the namespace?

Comment: A key item you left out is the LWC's import for the saveData method. Please [edit] your question to add it. BTW, why have the method accept a JSON string instead of the required parameters directly? JSON stringify/deserialize of your own is wasteful and inefficient.

Comment: BTW did you make any changes to your code base, other than adding the namespace for your scratch org?

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I made the changes to remove the wrapper class "TemplateWrapperTest" and created a new class for the wrapper. Below is the corrected wrapper class code:

```
public class TemplateWrapperTest{
    @AuraEnabled
    public String testStr1 {get;set;}
   @AuraEnabled
    public String testStr2 {get;set;}
}
```

**Below is the aura enabled method class that uses the above wrapper:**

```
public class classA {
    @AuraEnabled
        public static String saveData(TemplateWrapperTest thetemplateDetails){
    }
    }
```

**The below JS code is now working:**

```
var dataToSave = {
          testStr1 : this.contactCountryValue,
          testStr2 : this.contactStateValue,
        }
        saveData({ thetemplateDetails: dataToSave })
          .then(result => {
            this.showSpinner = false;
    }
```

Maybe the issue is that inner classes are not automatically given a namespace after enabling the namespace.